Will Bitcoin Core still respond quickly to a rpc-call when new blocks come in fast?
I had my Core Lightning node crash a few times because Bitcoin Core didn't respond in time to a rpc-call. I found that this happens when new blocks are generated quickly, like below:
849683  2024-06-27 14:46:02
849682  2024-06-27 14:44:11
849681  2024-06-27 14:43:30
3 blocks are found within 3 minutes, so 10 times as fast as on average (which can happen and is normal).
I increased my cpu-limit to mitigate the problem but that's beside my question below:
Does Bitcoin Core process rpc-calls during or in between incoming new blocks validation? What has precedence? How does it work in (more) detail?

Possibly related: Increase timeout in client - see my answer to seemingly unrelated question using timeout=120 in Python RPC client. See bitcoin-rpcclienttimeout in https://docs.corelightning.org/reference/lightningd-config

Thanks RedGrittyBrick, this is very useful on the CLN side
